# How should I implement a keybinded space function in python TKinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make a GUI using python's Tkinter Module that will make a picture of a spaceship land on a platform. I want to be able to keybind the spacebar so that it is an event that will increase the velocity of y(vy) by 3 meters/second. But for some reason, when I try to implement it , it doesn't work. This is my code, can anyone help me?

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

w,h= 800,600
g = -1.6
dt = 0.05
y = 100.0
vy = 0.0
t = 0.0

def tick():
   global y, vy, t
   y+= vy*dt
   vy += g*dt
   t+= dt
   print t, y, vy
   yp = 0.7*h-0.7*h*y/100.0
   canvas.coords(ship, w/4, yp)
   canvas.itemconfigure(txt,text='%0.2f'%vy)
   if y >= 0.0:
      canvas.after(1,tick)


root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = w, height = h, bg = 'black')
canvas.pack()

img1 = Image.open('earthrise.jpg').resize((w,h)) 
pmg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img1)
ship = canvas.create_image(w/2,h/2, image = pmg1)

img2 = Image.open('eagle.jpg').resize((200,200)) 
pmg2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
ship = canvas.create_image(w/4,0, image = pmg2)

canvas.create_rectangle(w/4-150, int(0.5+0.7*h)+100,w/4 + 150, 
int(0.5+0.7*h)+125, outline = 'green', fill = 'green')
f=('Times',36,'bold')
txt=canvas.create_text(w-100,50,text='0.0',font=f,fill='white')


def space(evt):

    vy+=3





root.bind('<space>',space)



print t,y,vy

canvas.after(1000, tick)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say it doesn't work? what is the error/problem?

Comment: You undoubtedly are getting an error message when you run this code. Have you done any research on the error message?

Comment: It does seem to work for me when I add `global vy` after `def space(evt):`.

Comment: Again, what does "doesn't work" mean? Does it add the wrong value? Does it add it to the wrong variable? Does it throw an error?